# TortoiseSVN with multiple users

Tags: delphi, tortoisesvn, delphi-2010

I have a server that multiple users RD into  to use. Installed is tortoiseSVN If settings are changed under one account will it effect the settings of another user?  Tortoise looks like the best option so far for an SVN client, everything else I have looked at is OSX only, Paid software, bloatware, or has terrible documentation. Any suggestions on what might be the best to use. Developers are using Embarcadero's Delphi 2010 RAD.

Answer (score 2):

Each OS user account gets their own Subversion user credentials cache and configuration file in `%APPDATA%\Subversion`. So as long as everyone has their own account on the server, their settings will have no effect on other users'.

Make sure each has their own working copy as well - WCs should never be shared between users for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can set TortoiseSVN to remember your user credentials after you enter them, or you can ignore that option and let TortoiseSVN prompt for credentials on every operation.  I don't know if that affects the IDE integration, though, as I use TortoiseSVN in Windows Explorer, no in the IDE.